# How can I assign preg_match results directly to variables?

Tags: php, preg-match

The following works in PHP:

```
preg_match("/a/", "a", $m);
list($zero) = $m;
```

But the following gives an error:

```
preg_match("/a/", "a", list($zero));
```

PHP documentation says `list()` is a language construct, but I'd like to understand specifically why this fails. Also, is there another way to assign results directly to variables (like `sscanf()`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer I can provide is not really satisfying I suppose. `list()` is like you said a language construct and it simply does not work like you used it in your second example. This is per definition, and cannot be changed.

I though of the use of `extract()` to get the variables, but this offends the PHP "strict standards, if you use it like this:

```
preg_match("/a/", "a", extract($m, EXTR_PREFIX_ALL, 'preg'));

Strict Standards:  Only variables should be passed by reference
```

I guess you will have to use a two line solution anyway, because of the by reference passing of `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 0):

The third argument in preg_match is an array.  By stating `$m` you are simply saying what the returned array of matches variable name is.  When you state `list()` it errors because `list()` is a language construct and it expects a variable name.  What you are asking to do (assign matching results directly to a variable) is already done.  $matches (`$m` in your case), is the variable.  It's a a variable of the type array.  Just var_dump your $m or echo out $m[0], $m[1], etc. to see the results.